# How to read long lines from child pocress' stdout in an efficient way?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, stdout, child-process

**Note:** This question has changed significantly since the first version, so some comments or answers could seem weird. Please, check the edit history if something seems weird.

I am launching a child process from a C# class library.

I am using `Process.BeginOutputReadLine()` to read the output/error in an asynchronous way. I thought it didn't work with very long lines, but the problem seems to be that it's not scalable. In my computer, a 128 kb line is processed instantly, a 512 kb line seems to take around one minute, 1 mb seems to take several minutes, and I've been around two hours waiting for a 10 mb line to be processed, and it was still working when I cancelled it.

It seems easy to fix reading directly from the StandardOutput and StandardError streams, but the data from those streams seems to be buffered. If I get wnough data from stdout to fill the buffer, and then some more data from stderr, I can't find a way to check if there's data pending in one of them, and if I try to read from stderr, it will hang forever.
Why is this happening, what am I doing wrong, and what's the right way to do this?

Some code samples to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

`Program1`:

> ```
>     // Writes a lot of data to stdout and stderr
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         int numChars = 512 * 1024;
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numChars);
>
>         String s = "1234567890";
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++)
>             sb.Append(s[i % 10]);
>
>         int len = sb.Length;
>         Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
>         Console.Error.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
>     }
> ```

`Program2`:

> ```
>     // Calls Program1 and tries to read its output.
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>        StringBuilder sbErr = new StringBuilder();
>
>        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
>        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
>        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
>
>        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
>        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
>        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
>
>        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
>        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "program1.exe";
>
>        proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ee) => { if (ee.Data != null) sbErr.AppendLine(ee.Data); };
>        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, ee) => { if (ee.Data != null) sb.AppendLine(ee.Data); };
>
>        proc.Start();
>        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
>        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
>        proc.WaitForExit();
>     }
> ```

`Program1` has a constant that allows to set the size of data to generate, and `Program2` launches `Program1` and tries to read the data. I should expect the time to grow linearly with size, but it seems much worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your problem. the application hangs on `Process.WaitForExit()` because this is what `Process.WaitForExit()`: [it waits for the process to exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx).

you might want to call it in a new thread:
int your method that create the process:

```
    Thread trd = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Start));
     trd.Start();
```

and add this method:

```
  private void Start(object o)
  {
     ((Process)o).WaitForExit();
     // your code after process ended
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn't explain my problem correctly. I know what WaitForExit does, the name is pretty clear :) The problem is that I have a program that writes a lot of data to stdout and stderr and then it just ends. When I call it with a Process object, it never ends and doesn't raise the DataReceived events.

Comment: @JaimePardos i do not know DataRecived event, i guess you are talking on OutputDataReceived. the OutputDataReceived event should go up when the process write to it's standard output.  you can see an example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx

Comment: I mean both, OutputDataReceived and ErrorDataReceived. I know what they do. The problem is that in my example they don't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that it works, but it's very, very slow with large sets of data, so I have reworded the question.